# How can a circuit be unexpectedly affected by change in light levels?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have (or rather, had) a completely functioning circuit the monitored input from a button to toggle an integrated LED on and off.

Much to my surprise, the circuit has very suddenly become finicky with light levels.
I have a lamp where I work and, when I block the light shining down on the button and its connections, the button's LED goes on the fritz.
Why could this be happening?

I have double-checked to make sure that I don't have any short circuits.
Is there anything physical that could be causing this, or is this purely a software issue?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDURza.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @JohnRennie That's fair, if they can give me a physical explanation.  The domain is certainly more specific.  This ended up being fixed with a software pull-up resistor.

Comment: in a comment on the physics side, you said you're looking for a physics explanation. We might be able to give you that if you provide a schematic for your circuit. On EE.SE you can embed a schematic by hitting the the schematic-button (or with Ctrl-M) while editing your question.

Comment: Were you blocking the light by moving your hand over the circuit? If so, I'll bet dollars to doughnuts that your body capacitance is really what caused your floating input to change state.

Comment: Yes exactly… Wow! Yeah it didn't happen with paper. I keep forgetting we have a charge of our own

Comment: I figured as much. I've seen it happen many times. (Done it myself, once or twice) Circuit isn't working, so I reach over to adjust something, suddenly it works. Pull my hand away, circuit stops working again. One of the cardinal rules of digital circuitry: **Never Leave Your Inputs Floating.**

Comment: @jwygralak67 Noted and tattooed on my hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment I see that your problem was fixed by enabling a pullup resistor in the microcontroller.

That means your original circuit was **not** "completely functional".  It apparently happened to work in the particular case you tested it at that temperature, at that humidity, with those specific parts, at exactly that supply voltage, and apparently that specific light level.

This is what happens when you violate specs.  In this case you ignored the minimum high and maximum low logic level specs for the input pin.  These are clearly spelled out in the datasheet, along with the maximum pin leakage current in input mode.  Putting all this together, it means the logic state of a floating input is not guaranteed, in addition of course to the usual it being a bad idea for other reasons.

The switch will pull the line solidly one way (apparently low in your case) when closed.  The problem is what happens when the switch is open.  Without something making sure that the pin voltage is above its minimum guaranteed logic high threshold, anything can happen.  This is what the pullup resistor fixed.  It sources more current onto the pin at the minimum logic high level than the pin can leak out, thereby guaranteeing it will be seen as a logic high when nothing else is connected.

The reason light mattered is because various substances can change conductivity slightly depending on light level.  Semiconductor junctions are even more susceptible to light, which is in fact the basis of how photocells work.  Since you were operating the device outside of specs, there was no guarantee of anything, and you got what you got, which in this case happened to be light sensitivity.  The same problem could have occurred at different temperatures, different humidities, and different parts, even from the same batch.

**READ THE DATASHEET** next time.

Comment: In my defense, I did read the datasheet when I originally implemented the system and the first iteration of its software. I left out the pull-up on accident when I implemented the second (and current) system using a more efficient paradigm. At least now I know why! Thanks! Didn't know that these things were so sensitive, but the mention of photocells (and I presume other environment sensors) gives the physical nature of the circuit more weight than I had bargained for.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this is a classic weird effect discussed in EDN magazine last year:  slightly slightly transparent IC packages.   If you used resistors to set the on/off thresholds coming from the button, and the threshold was too close to logic switching level, then light/dark on the CPU can shift things.    So, look for flakiness while casting a shadow on different components.   The pushbutton input pin doesn't float when on or off, correct?

Comment: If by on/off you mean the component being powered/unpowered, then no it doesn't flicker.  So weird.

Comment: No, I meant the pushbutton signal being on/off.  For example, if its CMOS input, pushing the button should cause your resistors to pull the input pin to 0V, and releasing it should pull the input pin to Vcc.   If instead it ever hangs around Vcc/2, or if the input pin is left floating when pushed/unpushed button, then the weird light sensitivity stuff can take it over.

Comment: Any chance you could get some sort of link to the article in EDN magazine? I'd have never guessed that sort of problem would ever exist. +1 for the info, though!